# Cant seem to get new alias 'winget' to override the 'winget' cli name

Tags: powershell

So I am getting tired of having to parse the output of `winget list` myself every time:

```
Name                                               Id                                                        Version         Available      Source
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NVM for Windows 1.1.11                             CoreyButler.NVMforWindows                                 1.1.11          1.1.12         winget
Visual Studio Build Tools 2022                     Microsoft.VisualStudio.2022.BuildTools                    17.7.6          17.8.6         winget
Signal 6.42.0                                      OpenWhisperSystems.Signal                                 6.42.0          6.46.0         winget
ImageMagick 7.1.1-8 Q16-HDRI (64-bit) (2023-04-22) ImageMagick.ImageMagick                                   7.1.1.8         7.1.1.27       winget
Adobe After Effects 2024                           AEFT_24_1                                                 24.1
...
```

I discovered there is a PowerShell module for winget, its pre release but it works fine and more importantly it allows me to work with `winget` the PowerShell way.

First order of business, I want to assign the alias `winget` to the command `Find-WinGetPackage`:

```
Set-Alias -name Find-WinGetPackage  -Value winget
```

But this does not work. Calling `winget` actually calls the winget cli tool found at `~\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\winget.exe`:

```
Get-Command winget  
#...Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\winget.exe
```

I thought aliases always over wrote native command names??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should read [Microsoft Learn on `Set-Alias`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-alias?view=powershell-7.4). If you want to be able to type `winget` and have the system execute the script cmdlet `Find-WinGetPackage`, you need to ‘flip’ the parameters for your `Set-Alias` command above:

```
Set-Alias -Name winget -Value Find-WinGetPackage
```

The ‘name’ of the alias is what you want to type; the ‘value’ is what you want it to pretend you typed.

Comment: That was embarassing. I spent a good hour of the morning fiddling with this. Thank you for your help.